# Left zeros in awk lead to different results

Tags: awk, format

I notice the follow sentence

```
 echo | awk '{OFMT="%.16e";CONVFMT="%.16e";print 10.-0.1*011}'
```

gives 9.0999999999999996e+00

and this one

```
 echo | awk '{OFMT="%.16e";CONVFMT="%.16e";print 10.-0.1*11}'
```

gives 8.9000000000000004e+00

Notice the zero at the left side in 11. This result difference is ok?

Thanks

Comment: In both cases I get `8.9000000000000004e+00`. I am working on `mawk 1.3.3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `011` is parsed as an octal value. If you do

```
$ echo | awk '{OFMT="%.16e";CONVFMT="%.16e";print 10.-0.1*9}'
9.0999999999999996e+00
```

You get the same result, because 9 in decimal is 011 in octal

Comment: Thanks for info.  This is a pitfall not easy to see.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, sorry for the delay to check the solution mark.